# Why does String.prototype.replace remove "$'" from my string?

Tags: javascript, ios, string, replace, automation

I'm not using JQuery, so I don't think that's causing the trouble. I first ran into this using the iOS automation tool and then went to verify it using JSFiddle. If anyone can show me a way around this it would fantastic.

```
var str = "<'pass!23$'>";
var str1 = str.replace("<'pass!23$'>", "'pass!23$'");
var str2 = str.replace("<'pass!23$'>", "'pass!23$a'");
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adUtw/

This is really confusing me!

Comment: Because `$'` has special meaning in regex.

Comment: This [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`string.replace` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), you'll notice that `$` alone has some special meanings for replace. Therefore, if you want to insert a `$` you need to use `$$`.

Your replace statement would then look like:

```
var str1 = str.replace("<'pass!23$'>", "'pass!23$$'");
```

You can verify it is working by updating the Fiddle.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't think the $ would mean anything special if the first argument wasn't a regex.

Comment: That is truly bizarre. So if I do something like str.replace('$', '$$') can I avoid this issue? There won't be any regex being used in my code that this issue showed up in.

Comment: Oops, I had the right idea but actually had to do replace('$', '$$$$') because the string is eval'ed later in the script.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is [interpreted in a special way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) when it appears in the second argument to `replace`.

It is used to refer to regex *groups* defined in the first argument:

```
'abc'.replace('(b)', 'XY$1Z') === 'aXYbZc'
```

And `$'` is interpreted as the `portion of the string that follows the matched substring.`

To use a `$` in the second argument, escape it by saying `$$`.

```
var str1 = str.replace("<'pass!23$'>", "'pass!23$$'");
```

Comment: So perhaps curiously if you have  arbitrary replacement string which MAY contain $s you must replace the possible $s in it  WITH  '$$$$' . For instance  '$'.replace ('$', '$$$$') === '$$' and so now that is a valid value for the replacement parameter. Tricky